# Picture submit to database blob and control size

Tags: coldfusion

I have a registration page that will submit all the registration values into MS SQL database. I am trying to control the size of the image that is updated to the database to be width=125 height=125. Is there a way to control that before it is submitted into the database?

Also is this the most recent way to submit it into the database?(The most recent I could find was 2011)
**FORM**

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="cfm/register_process.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="employee_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Number" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="phone_extension" class="form-control" placeholder="Extension" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Select image
                    <input type="file" name="filefieldname" id="filefieldname" multiple />
                    </span>
                 </span>
                 <input id="filename" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <span class="btn btn-primary cleared">Reset</span>
                 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox"><i></i> Agree the terms and policy </label></div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>

            <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.html">Login</a>
        </form>
```

**Then the form calls register_process.cfm and submits to database**

```
    <cffile action="readbinary" file="#form.filefieldname#" variable="bin_filedata">

<cfquery datasource="test" name="UserRegistration">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Users (employee_number, user_name, user_pass, firstname, lastname, position, email, phone_extension, department, picture)
 VALUES (
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.employee_number#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.user_name#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.user_pass#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.firstname#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.lastname#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.position#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.email#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.phone_extension#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#form.department#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#bin_filedata#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_blob' />
 )
</cfquery>

<script>  
    self.location="../login.html"; 
</script>
```

[image]

Unfortunately when I try to submit this I just get an all white screen and it does not update the database. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the picture.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  There is too much chaff hiding the wheat.  All those irrelevent form fields can go away.  Then maybe we can see the attempt to look at the size of the image.

Comment: Firstly you need to 'POST' your data, so set the form to `method="post"`, secondly, you need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` with file uploads. Then use `cffile` with an action of upload - have a look at: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html cfimage can be used to resizing https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfimage.html Finally use `ImageGetBlob` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7971.html

Comment: am I able to use the cffile on the register_process.cfm page ? or does it have to be on the form page?

Comment: you do the file upload on the page that the form submits to, in your case `cfm/register_process.cfm`

Comment: hmmm I wonder whats going wrong its not submitting to the database and the cfm/register_process.cfm page seems correct but its getting stuck here and shows all the values in the url

Comment: If the values are in the URL, then you are not 'post'ing the form.

Comment: your right there not there any more but now its just a blank white screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99961/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-john-whish).